# What is the limit of WebSockets connections in Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, websocket

I have a web site using node.js in Windows Azure, its mode is set to Standard. This post (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx) states that the limit for the number of WebSocket connections in Standard mode is 350.

However I am getting the following error all the time: `"HTTP Error 503.0 - Number of active WebSocket requests has reached the maximum concurrent WebSocket requests allowed."`. Yet only 10 people were testing the site. What can be the reason for this? Is the limit of 350 connections not true?

Comment: I don't suppose it was the same problem as in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/cf5842c9-76ce-4438-810d-6039e18553b0/debugging-aspnet-web-role-requests-executing-capped-at-10?forum=windowsazuredevelopment)?

Comment: I don't think so, I'm not running the site locally, I am running it in the cloud.

Comment: The problem in that thread was that the client making the HTTP connections to the site in the cloud didn't support more than 10 connections.